# Why use strcmp instead of equal comparison to determine URI scheme

Tags: php, url, parse-url

In a class file, I saw the following code:

```
$uriParts = parse_url($uri);
$this->port = strcmp('https', $uriParts['scheme']) ? 80 : 443;
```

I know, the part `$uriParts['scheme']` provides either of the schemes like http, https, ftp or anything but why the above line used `strcmp` function instead of using the following code

```
$this->port = ('https' !== $uriParts['scheme']) ? 80 : 443;
```

Doest it have any specific reason or just like that??

Comment: There is no reason. In PHP, they would probably yield the same result. That person probably came from a C background and is used to calling `strcmp` on two strings.

Comment: This code is screwed up anyway. The URI may contain a port already, but it is seemingly being ignored entirely, instead assuming a hardcoded port number.

Comment: as per the documentation, the "scheme" part will only give the scheme of URI and there is no matter of port in this situation.

Comment: I'm saying, if `$uri` is `http://example.com:42/`, then the port specification of `42` will be ignored entirely and overwritten with `80` purely based on the scheme. I'd assume this may potentially cause a problem. A scheme does not always equal a certain port is what I'm saying.

Comment: Ok ! I thought about the port with scheme. Thanks